# Using a Bezier curve to represent a circle

Tags: bezier

Using a Bezier curve to represent a quadrant of a circle, with start and end points (0,1) and (1,0) and control points (k,1) and (1,k) the optimum value for k is 0.551914972 giving an error of about half that where the mid point lies on the true circle. (For some reason I can't seem to post this as an answer, but only as a question.)

Comment: an answer to what question? Circle is exactly representable as a *rational* NURBS  curve (i.e. w CPs having non-unit weights). Beziers are non-rational (all CPs w a unit weight, 1.0).

Comment: That is most certainly **not** the optimum `k` value. [The mathematically correct optimal value](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic) is `4/3 * (sqrt(2)-1)`, which is 0.55228474983[...] - That said, did you remove your question text, instead of adding your own (incorrect) answer as an edit? Because as is, this post should be deleted, since it doesn't ask for anything to be answered.